# Distribution of elements in ideal class groups of imaginary quadratic orders

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $X$ be a large positive number. Put $h(d)$ for the size of the ideal class group of the quadratic order of discriminant $d$, or equivalently,

$$\displaystyle h(d) = \#\{\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\text{-orbits of integral binary quadratic forms of discriminant } d\}.$$

Put $C(d)$ for the ideal class group of the quadratic order of discriminant $d$, and for each positive integer $m$ put $C_m(d)$ to be the subgroup of $C(d)$ consisting of those elements of order dividing $m$. Consider the homomorphism $\rho$ of $C(d)$ to itself defined by $w \mapsto w^4$. The kernel of this map is precisely $C_4(d)$.

We now suppose $d > 0$, and suppose that each class $w \in C(-d)$ is parametrized by a reduced form $f_w = a_w x^2 + b_w xy + c_w y^2$, so that $|b_w| \leq a_w \leq c_w, a_w, c_w > 0$.

Is the set

$$\displaystyle R(X) = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 : |b| \leq a \leq c, a, c \geq 1, 4ac - b^2 \leq X, a < X^{1/4}\}$$

well-distributed with respect to $\rho$? More precisely, for a given $d > 0$ we identify the subset of $C(-d)$ given by $C^\dagger(-d) = \{w \in C(d) : f_w \in R(X)\}$ and ask whether or not $\# (C^\dagger(-d)/C_4(-d)) \approx \#C^\dagger(-d)/\# C_4(-d)$ (here the left hand side should read "cardinality of $C^\dagger(-d)$ modded out by $C_4(-d)$"), at least on average as $X$ tends to infinity.